# Windows File Explorer (+ other applications) "Application not found"

Tags: windows-explorer

### The problem

In Windows File Explorer I cannot navigate to a folder in the main view. If I double-click a folder or if I right click and then select 'open', I get an error saying "Application not found". I can, however, expand the folder on the navigation menu on the left side, so there is no problem with my access permissions (I just granted myself Full Control of the folders I am trying to open).

I get the same error message when I try to start some programs by typing its name in the Windows menu and hitting Enter. The error appears when I try to open File Explorer, Control panel and some other programs, but not when I try to open e.g. Word or Chrome.

### What I tried

- granting myself Full Control of the folder
- running programs (like Control panel) by navigating to their location and double-clicking them; they give the same error "Application not found"

### Possible cause of problem

- Maybe File Explorer, Control panel and some others have not been added to my System Path? I wouldn't know how to add them though.

Comment: Try to test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html). Run also deep antivirus scans by your antivirus and [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/mwb-download).

Comment: I have not had this issue with any recent version of Windows.  File Explorer and Control Panel do not need to be separately added to path.  Did the permission and other changes damage the OS?  Try a different Windows User Profile to see if your issues are are resolved that way